# How to get value of input field in typescript file Angular 4

Tags: angular

```
 <div id="lists">
            <table id='mytable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                <tr  class="row" [ngClass]="{'selected': i === selectedIndex}"  *ngFor= 'let item of list; let i = index' [attr.data-index]='i'  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': i%2 == '0' ? 'gray' : ''}">
                    <td class='default-field'>
                        <p class='para' *ngIf="selectedIndex!=i  ">{{i+1}}. {{item}}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit-field" *ngIf="selectedIndex==i   " >
                        <input type="text" class="myCl" [value]="val" >
                    </td>
                    <td class='btns'>

                    <input type='button' value='edit' class='edit-btn'  (click)='hidePara(item,i)' *ngIf="selectedIndex!=i">

                    <input type='button' value='save' class='save-btn' *ngIf="selectedIndex==i" (click)='hidePara1(item,i)'> 
                    <input type='button' value='DELETE' class='delete-btn' (click)='deleterow(i)'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
```

Above is my html code, i want to **retrieve the value** of input field when user click on save button, the **hidePara1(item,i)** function will execute, i want to get **value** of input field in hidepara1, how this can be possible.

```
 hidePara1(item,ii)
 {
  this.selectedIndex=-1;
  this.showHideP = !this.showHideP;  //for hiding paragraph
  this.tbox = !this.tbox;  //showing text box
  this.edt=!this.edt;  //hide edt button
  this.sbtn = !this.sbtn;  //display save button 

 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you need to import `FormsModule` in `app.modules.ts` in order to use `ngModel`

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Then you can use `[(ngModel)]` to get the value in `.ts` file

HTML :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputText">
```

TS :

```
inputText :string = "I am sample text";
```

**Your code becomes :**

```
 <div id="lists">
            <table id='mytable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                <tr  class="row" [ngClass]="{'selected': i === selectedIndex}"  *ngFor= 'let item of list; let i = index' [attr.data-index]='i'  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': i%2 == '0' ? 'gray' : ''}">
                    <td class='default-field'>
                        <p class='para' *ngIf="selectedIndex!=i  ">{{i+1}}. {{item}}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit-field" *ngIf="selectedIndex==i   " >
                        <input type="text" class="myCl" [value]="val" [(ngModel)]="item.inputText">
                    </td>
                    <td class='btns'>

                    <input type='button' value='edit' class='edit-btn'  (click)='hidePara(item,i)' *ngIf="selectedIndex!=i">

                    <input type='button' value='save' class='save-btn' *ngIf="selectedIndex==i" (click)='hidePara1(item,i)'> 
                    <input type='button' value='DELETE' class='delete-btn' (click)='deleterow(i)'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
```

Comment: i write console.log(item.value) in hidepara1 function it show me error....   

I also use console.log(item) which give me undefined

Comment: Can you update `hidePara1()` function code in question ?

Comment: i have added function in question

Comment: I have updated answer, now change only `(click)='hidePara(item,i)'`

Comment: sangwin the input field is editable when i write console.log(item) in my para1 function it shows me previous value not new value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159121/discussion-between-kappo-and-sangwin-gawande).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
 <td class="edit-field" *ngIf="selectedIndex==i" >
      <input type="text" class="myCl" [(ngModel)]="val" >
 </td>
```

Comment: I tried this already and it's not working, because it require onclick within the same scope, so for this reason  hidePara1(item,i)  cannot use its value

Answer (score 0):

`value` is the property of this component by using Input field.use `[(ngmodel)]`

`<input type="text" class="myCl" [(ngmodel)]="value[i]" >`

get value from input field and store the value of array by ng model method then click the save button pass array valy and parameter to save

`<input type='button' value='save' class='save-btn' *ngIf="selectedIndex==i" (click)='hidePara1(value,item,i)'>`

Comment: It is showing this error:

Can't bind to 'ngmodel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("it-field" *ngIf="selectedIndex==i   " >
                            <input type="text" class="myCl" [ERROR ->][(ngmodel)]="value[i]" >
                        </td>

Comment: register `formsmodule` in app module
`import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({ 
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule]}, providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
 
})


export class AppModule { }`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PyIe4gZJqr7qjiyt7T3Z7D9qi_hCOjnW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `ngModel` instead of  `ngmodel`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159120/discussion-between-vignesh-hawkeye-and-kappo).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jZKVVW5XIkerA6t-FgpfZeJCam9zCy24/view?usp=sharing

Comment: define `value=[]` in .ts file  for example `export class AppComponent {
  value=[];
}
`